# C#: get all files based on regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a folder which contains multiple `Zip` files with different naming convention.

1. `1.zip`
2. `Hello.zip`
3. `SomeNameWithAnyCharacter-Xal_Yal_Zal_12345-20180518-152147535.zip`

I would like to get all zip files which has below naming convention:

```
[SomeNameWithAnyCharacter]-[Xal_Yal_Zal_][yyyyMMdd][HHmmssfff]
```

How to apply *regex* for below code in C#,

```
var allFiles = Directory
  .GetFiles(@"C:\FilePath", "*.zip")
  .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
  .OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastWriteTimeUtc);
```

Comment: thats nice.. what have you tried .. I dont see any name matching in your linq

Comment: `*.zip` give me all the files, can I put Regex over here, then how?

Comment: in your select match the regex expression on name.......

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for GetFiles? You are already using wildcards in there - potentially just using its other wildcard options might do you... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx . It doesn't do regex but if something like `*-[Xal_Yal_Zal_]*.zip` would do the job then that's an option.

Comment: You know, there is an entire world of string manipulation *outside* regexes... you don't know regexes, don't use regexes. the world will continue to go on, and your code will still run.

Comment: Also you have two potential questions here and I'm not sure which you are stuck on  - 1) How can I make a regex that does this 2) How can I filter my files based on a regex I have for the filename. Which part are you actually stuck on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `Where` with required *regular expression*:

```
  var allFiles = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\FilePath", "*.zip")
    .Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),   // match file name
      @"Xal_Yal_Zal_[0-9]+-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{9}$"))  // with the required regex
    .Select(file => new FileInfo(file))
    .OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastWriteTimeUtc);
```

Pattern: `Xal_Yal_Zal_[0-9]+-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{9}$` explained:

```
Xal_Yal_Zal_ - Xal_Yal_Zal_ 
[0-9]+       - one or more digits 0..9
-            - minus sign
[0-9]{8}     - 8 digits 0..9, e.g. 20180518
-            - minus sign
[0-9]{9}     - 9 digits 0..9, e.g. 152147535
$            - anchor - end of string
```

Comment: Technically you should post (after the regex)-check for the validity of the dates (for example by using a `DateTime.TryParse`) :-) But we will ignore this detail :-) Ah... and probably it would be better to put the regex in a variable, so it is compiled once instead of interpreted once for every file.